# 2 Controllers In 1 View - Data Not Submitting From Form

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to resolve. I have a single page application where the controllers are being handled by routeProvider. Within one of the view files (order.html), I would like to bring in data from another controller (customersController) and use it in a select/option drop down menu. However, since I'm calling another controller directly in the view file, the customersController is overriding the ordersController and thus, is preventing the ng-model from being seen by the ordersController. My problem is, whenever I submit a new order, the order.name does not get passed into the scope. Order.quantity and order.product show up just fine.

Here is the orders.html view page:

```
<h2>Add New Order</h2>
<form>
    <label for="name">Customer</label>
    <select name="name" ng-model="order.name" ng-controller="customersController" ng-options="customer.name for customer in customers">
    </select>
    <label for="quantity">Order</label>
    <select name="quantity" ng-model="order.quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select name="product" ng-model="order.product">
        <option value="Nike Shoes">Nike Shoes</option>
        <option value="Black Belts">Black Belts</option>
        <option value="Ice Creams">Ice Creams</option>
        <option value="Candies">Candies</option>
        <option value="Waffles">Waffles</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Order" ng-click="addOrder()">
</form>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
            <td>{{ order.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ order.date }}</td>
            <td><a href="#/" ng-click="deleteOrder(order._id)">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now one way to solve this issue is by injecting the customersFactory into the ordersController but I am not sure if this is the proper way of solving this issue. It seems like a cheap band aid fix since every time the ordersController is used, it will now contain the customersFactory. That kind of defeats the purpose of having a multiple controllers since I can just inject a generic controller with a bunch of factories.

Any suggestions or ideas on what I can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant that injecting the customersFactory into the ordersController feels like a band-aid fix. I believe there should be a way to keep the customersFactory separate from the ordersController and just use ng-controller within the view file to bring in the customer data while still being able to use the ng-model which references the ordersController.

Comment: You can inject orderController in the HTML, and customerController, this will work, I don't know why do you say that this seem like a cheap

Comment: The select is part of the form ?@StockDC2

Comment: Yes it is. It seems that the formatting got messed up when pasting it into stackoverflow. Fixing it now.

Comment: How is it a band-aid fix to inject a service, that provides the functionality you need, in a controller? That's how services are meant to be used.

Comment: Oh, it very well might not be but it just feels kind of weird since the customers will be in the scope whenever I use the ordersController. If this is the correct method though, no complaints from me!